# some random php code is showing to the top of wordpress websites

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

When I open my WordPress websites. It's showing this code on the top of the browser. I can see its a PHP code without a starting code. where could I found this line of code?

Comment: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: That looks like your WP got infected by something. There are a lot of guides out there explaining what to do in such a case, so go and follow some of those to try and get your system clean again.

Answer (score -3):

check your index.php file any print exit written